# AttributeError: 'TextCtrl' object has no attribute 'ClearAll

Tags: user-interface, wxpython, reset, listctrl, wxtextctrl

I have both textctrl and listctrl in my Parent frame. I want to erase both the teletext and listctrl in one click. so when the reset button is clicked it should erase all text and list.How do i accomplish this?
I am trying this but that gives me error

```
    self.reset_btn=wx.Button(p,-1,"Reset!")
    self.reset_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnReset, self.reset_btn)
    bs.Add(self.reset_btn,0,wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

def OnReset(self, event):                                    
    self.list.ClearAll()
    self.text.ClearAll()
```

Comment: It might help to post the error you receive so others have a better idea of the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, instead it has `Clear` instead.

```
self.text.Clear()
```

In anticipation of your next question, which might well be, when I have run `ClearAll` on my `ListCtrl`, why do I get `invalid item column`, when trying to repopulate the data in the listctrl?
Because `ClearAll` will have done just what it said on the tin, it cleared everything. So you will have to redo the `InsertColumn()` commands, that you initially did.

So, instead of using `self.list.ClearAll()` use `self.list.DeleteAllItems()` which only clears the data.